# Intermittent ProviderException from IIS or MVC: API failed due to error 'The data area passed to a system call is too small. '

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis, asp.net-membership, authorization, windows-server-2008-r2

Running IIS 7.5.7600.16385 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise (7601: SP1). One of our websites is set to globally log errors and we are seeing this every day or two. We're using an authorization attribute in our web.config that checks for user roles for access and whatever code IIS or MVC uses is generating this error. This is typically being triggered by a single partial view but we also see it triggered occasionally on fetching css or js resources.

```
System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderException: API failed due to error 'The data area passed to a system call is too small. '
at System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider.GetRolesForUser(String username)
at System.Web.Security.RolePrincipal.IsInRole(String role)
at System.Web.Configuration.AuthorizationRule.IsTheUserInAnyRole(StringCollection roles, IPrincipal principal)
at System.Web.Configuration.AuthorizationRule.IsUserAllowed(IPrincipal user, String verb)
at System.Web.Configuration.AuthorizationRuleCollection.IsUserAllowed(IPrincipal user, String verb)
at System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule.OnEnter(Object source, EventArgs eventArgs)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Do we maybe have some IIS setting for our website incorrect? Any idea what is going on? We can see by the username in our logs that the user is being correctly authenticated through IWA.

Comment: We are also experiencing the same issue. Did you ever manage to fix this?

Comment: Nope, never did. Just had to downgrade it to a warning and accept the occasional connection erroring out.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try a bit more to see whether I can figure it out on my side. If I do find anything I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: @Jamie or Brian did either of you find a solution or workaround to this? if it were my code i could change it but this seems to surround built in functionality of MVC.

Comment: Nope. We moved the app to another server after we started having random network hangs and decommissioned the old ones and haven't seen either issue on the new servers.

Comment: Similar - I assume it was just a bad server or configuration with AD